# Probability of value being less than or equal to "x"

Tags: probability, self-study, mean, standard-deviation, sample-size

I'm a bit stuck trying to find the probability of a certain value being less than or equal to "x" in a normal distribution. I know the population mean (400), population standard deviation (20), sample size (25) and my target value "x" (395).

Can you explain how I could calculate what is the probability to get less than or equal to "x"?

Comment: Hi Xi'an, indeed it is self-study, I've added the tag, thank you for bringing this to my attention. I'm stuck understanding which formula to use. I thought this is going to be solved using NORM.DIST in Excel but I cannot wrap around my head how to use the given values.

Comment: You might want to look into the concept of a cumulative distribution function (CDF), e.g. this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)

Comment: Also, look into t distribution instead of normal distribution. Normal distribution is good when sample size is large (about 120 or above). When sample size is small, t distribution is a better choice.

Comment: @RubenvanBergen, if I understand correctly my question, I am looking at NORM.DIST with TRUE (so I get CDF). I tried that with the values I have but oddly I don't get an acceptable answer. If I calculate =NORM.DIST(x=395,mean=400,stdev=20,cumulative=TRUE) and I get approximately 0.40, which is not the right answer

Comment: What makes you think that this is not the right answer?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen, I am doing a quiz with possible answer. This is not one of them and I have confidence they have put the correct answer as one of the options :)

Comment: CV does not cover basic programming questions, neither in Excel nor in another language.

Comment: The question is not well defined - do you want the random variable X to be less than 395, or do you want the sample average to be less than 395? If the first, than n=25 is irrelevant. If the second, than you are using the wrong standard deviation which may cause your wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the question clearer from a mathematical point of view, it seems you are looking for the value of the probability
\begin{align*}
p &= \mathbb{P}(\bar{X}_n\le x_0)\\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} \varphi(\bar{x}_n;\mu,\sigma) \text{d}\bar{x}_n
\end{align*}
when
$$\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\qquad X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
and
$$n=25\quad\mu=400\quad \sigma=20\ x_0=395$$

**Hint #1:** Derive the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$ as a Normal distribution with appropriate mean and appropriate variance.

**Hint #2:** Express the cdf of the $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution in terms of the cdf $\Phi$ of the standard $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution, $\mu$, and $\sigma$.